# convert speech into text in excel - can this be done

Tags: excel, speech-to-text

I am working on a form, for which I would rather not rely on the one fingered typists in the workshop to fill in (with the inevitable typo's).  Therefore I wondered if anyone know how to speak directly into some cells in excel and have that speech turned into text?

I have searched the net and constantly find the text to speech option which is the exact opposite of what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question might be more appropriate for a different site (e.g. https://superuser.com/), here's some information that's out there.

Windows has built-in support to speech-to-text. [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14198/windows-7-dictate-text-using-speech-recognition) is for Windows 7, but I was able to do something similar to get it to work for Windows 10 (I'm not sure what version of Windows your shop uses). I'm sure there are other commercial products you can use.

With Windows 10, I had to enable speech services, then use the `Win+H` keyboard shortcut to activate dictation. With Excel open and in focus, anything I said was entered into the active cell.